# Where should I install the Bridge server

Tags: bridge-currency

I have been working on a project that is hosted of site. I am worried about putting the bridge server in the root folder with all the info it holds.

Answer (score 1):

The way you ask your question seems to imply you think of the bridge server as working like a PHP application where you drop files in a folder and then immediately the app becomes available to the world.

The bridge server is meant to be run as a standalone process and exposed only through an HTTP port. It does not publish the files within its installation directory through the HTTP endpoint.

To host a bridge server, simply configure it and run it on a server. You'll need full access to the server host, not just access to drop files like most of the cheaper web hosts provide.